# What is that bubbled machine is Eddie using?

Tags: jumanji-the-next-level

In *Jumanji The Next Level* (2019), Eddie is shown wearing something on his head and it is connected 
to a bubbled machine:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a CPAP (aka *Continuous Positive Airway Pressure* or *Sleep Apnea Machine*) used to treat sleep apnea.

> Continuous positive airway pressure (CPAP) therapy is the frontline treatment for obstructive sleep apnea. CPAP therapy keeps your airway open during the night by gently providing a constant stream of air through a mask you wear while you sleep. This eliminates the breathing pauses caused by sleep apnea, so you will no longer snore or make choking noises in your sleep. You will be able to sleep through the night without your body waking up from a lack of oxygen.
> <sub>*source:* [CPAP - Overview](http://sleepeducation.org/essentials-in-sleep/cpap)</sub>

Using it in the scene implies Eddie's advanced age and related physical infirmity in real life. This sharply contrasts the fine physical specimen (Dr. Smolder Bravestone) that he becomes in the game.